# Auto Ads preview not showing styles - previously worked fine

Tags: reactjs, adsense

We recently pushed some updates to our website - and now our Google Auto Ads Preview isn't showing styles - which causes ad placement to not work.

When we run the site on any other Google tool (like Page Speed Test), it works as expected.

The website is built in React.

Any ideas?

Screenshot of ad preview: https://storage.googleapis.com/support-forums-api/attachment/thread-145625886-17524325518630940582.png

Comment: Do you see errors in console when you open Auto Ads Preview? It should be showing your site (or copy of the site) in an iframe. I'd check if you see any JS/networks errors and whether you see requests to your CSS files.

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @GippyAulakh - we didn't. We ended up changing ad platforms.